# Define with regex for js where allow any two decimal places after 4 except 404

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey guys I'm looking for some with a regular expression. I'm looking to define a regex for JS where allow any two decimal places after 4 except 404

so basically

```
400 = valid  
401 = valid  
402 = valid  
403 = valid  
404 = invalid  
405 = valid
```

So far I have something like this to restrict it to starting from number 4 and two decimal places after.

```
.match(/4\d{2}/)
```

Could someone give me a helping hand with the restriction of 404 place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try in this way to exclude 4 in last digit

```
/^4[0-9][0-35-9]$/
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/bJ5aV3/4)

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  4                        '4'
  [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
  [0-35-9]                 any character of: '0' to '3', '5' to '9'
  $                        the end of the string
```

---

You can do in this way as well instead of defining the range

```
/^4[0-9][012356789]$/
```

---

For more info read about [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`.

---

To exclude `404` only do in the same way

```
/^4(0[0-35-9]|[1-9][0-9])$/
```

Comment: Hi can you please explain your expression to me? for example what is the [0-35-9] doing exactly?

Comment: @BaconJuice `[0-35-9]` is a character class that matches if the character is in range `0-3` or `5-9` - so any digit from `0-9` except 4.

Comment: This doesn't match 414, 424, 434 ..., 494 so doesn't match "any two decimal places after 4 except 404".

Comment: @MikeSamuel You have already answered it and there is no need to repeat it again.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
/^4(?!04)\d{2}$/
```

- `^` Anchors start of string.
- `4` Matches the digit **"4"**.
- `(?!04)` Asserts that we are not looking at **"04"**.
- `\d{2}` Match the two *digits*.
- `$` Anchors end of string.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nO8qS8/3)!

Answer (score 2):

The most readable regular expression uses a negative lookahead to explicitly exclude "404"

```
/^(?!404)4\d\d$/
```

This should work well.  If, for some reason, lookahead isn't supported, then

```
/^4(0[0-35-9]|[1-9]\d)$/
```

will match any three digit decimal integer that starts with 4 and is not 404 by matching (4 followed by (0 and a digit that is not 4, or any non-zero digit followed by another digit)).

You might find it more readable to say `[^4\D]` instead of `[0-35-9]`.  They mean the same thing, but the inverting of (non-digit and 4) to mean (digit and not 4) might be non-obvious to some.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?!04)` (negative lookahead) to say "not followed by `04`".

So you can do:

```
/4(?!04)\d{2}/
```

So this says "First match a `4`, then it must not be followed by `04`, then match any two digits".

Importantly, lookahead with `(?=...)` and `(?!...)` does not actually match characters, they only cause the match to fail if the condition is not met.